# Detecting if form has changed, script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, conditional-statements

I am trying to use the following script to detect if any fields in my form have changed (edit: detect if the values of my form fields have changed), and alert the user if so. Otherwise, another js box is displayed.

It's not detecting any changes though, and the confirm box is never shown. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#eventMedia').click(function() {
        var form_changed = false;

        $('#tribe-events > form').on('keyup change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
            form_changed = true;
        });

        if (form_changed == true) {
            confirm('You have unsaved changes! Click Cancel to save your changes before continuing.');
        } else {
            $('#eventMediaBox').show();
            $('#blackFade').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: "detect if any fields in my form have changed"?.... from what to what?

Comment: Sorry, detect if the values of any of my form fields have changed.

Comment: So what is #eventMedia? Is it being clicked after the form is filled in??? If that is the case, how would keyup or changes previously made be detected after the element was clicked. You need to bind them OUTSIDE of the click method.

Comment: Clicking #eventmedia brings up a new element on the page that allows the user to upload images. Once they save the uploaded images, the page refreshes and any unsaved changes in the form would be lost, therefore I want to alert the user beforehand.

Comment: So were the changes you want to detect made before the button was clicked or after? If before, my previous comment stands. If after, your  if is being checked when the element is not clicked. You are not calling it before the upload is happening...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting to register `keyup` and `change` events only once the `#eventMedia` button is clicked which is probably not the desired order of things.

instead:

```
// Set the boolean flag variable first
var form_changed = false;

// On `input change` events - set flag to truthy
$('#tribe-events > form').on('input change', 'input, select, textarea', function(){
    form_changed = true;
});

// Showtime!
$('#eventMedia').click(function() {
    if (form_changed) {
        alert('You have unsaved changes! Save your changes before continuing.');
    } else {
        $('#eventMediaBox, #blackFade').show();
    }
});
```

Notice that the `"input"` event (in `.on('input change'`) will also cover the cases where the user pastes content using mouse etc...

Also, don't forget to reset sometimes your `form_changed` back to `false` in your code...

---

Now thinking back to your UI... I have a question. "Why?". Yes, why show a "SAVE" or whatever `#eventMedia` does if the user did not changed anything in the form? I mean if a user did any changes than there's no reason to do anything - right?

This should suffice I think:

```
> button is disabled="true"
> (User makes changes?) on `input change` make enabled.
```

Comment: You can drop the `form_changed == true`. `if ( form_changed )` will suffice.
@roko-c-buljan

Comment: @KostasX sure but that's entirely on OP. Sometimes tricky programmers re-use the same variable to assign different type-values.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but you've already changed the OP code! This will make the code a little bit better too.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for the detailed answer and explanation. I'm not great with this stuff yet (obviously) and it helps when people explain their answers so I can learn. And Roko, I'm not that tricky, you're right about `form_change == true`.

Comment: @Eckstein you're welcome :) edited a bit my answer anyways.

Comment: To answer your question: #eventMedia displays an interface overlayed on the form that allows the user to upload images. When the image uploads are saved, the page refreshes so if they have changes the underlying form, the changes are not saved. The confirm box let's them know to save first before adding images.

Comment: @Eckstein I'm sad to hear that... :( you've could done that without any refresh by simply using a couple of lines of jQuery and AJAX.

Comment: Definitely correct, unfortunately I'm working in a plugin environment that generates most of the HTML and I don't have access to it, so it gets a bit tricky. Luckily your solution works for what I need though. :)